# Apache Spark concurrent program example

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency

I want the following simple hello world program to be executed 100 times in parallel in Apache Spark.

```
  public class SimpleHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
  }
```

So after executing in parallel, it should print "Hello World" 100 times.

How can I do this in standalone Apache Spark?

Comment: you realize that you will not see "Hello World" because these statements are executed on the worker nodes?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
Where I can define the number of threads/nodes that will run this program? I mean how to initiate multithreading here?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you really want:

1. Multi-Threading in Spark-Driver: e.g.

```
    import scala.collection.parallel._
    import scala.concurrent.forkjoin._
    val pool = (0 to 100).par
    // ThreadPool with 100 concurrent Threads
    pool.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(100))
    pool.foreach(i => {
        println("Hello World")
    })
```

2. "Multi-Threading" per Spark-Executor Task: e.g.

```
    // create 100 partitions
    var df = sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 100).toDF()
    // print "hello world" per each partition
    df.foreachPartition(_ => println("Hello World"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want in Scala with Spark 2.x:

```
sparkSession.range(100)
.foreach(_ => println("Hello World"))
```

But you won't see the printed lines on the driver because they are executed on the worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks Raphael!
Can you please explain what sparkSession.range will do?

Comment: @pankaj it will generate a `Dataset[Long]` with values from 0 to 99

Comment: Acutally my requirement is that I want to run this program independently with no RDD sharing between them. My program will be fetching the data from some web services and do calculation and then store in database. Is Spark good choice here to initiate parallel independent task?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want running spark machine for this case.

For Spark job that you need the first initiation your RDD. then use the Spark action or transformation functions for data computation.  Also, spark it running parallel automatically.

```
   public class hello world {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                try (JavaSparkContext sc = setupSparkContext()) {

            JavaRDD<String> helloworldRDD = sc.textFile("//your hellworld file");
                helloworldRDD.map(x->{
                    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){

                        System.out.println(x);

                    }
                    return x;

                }).collect();
        }
        }

        private static JavaSparkContext setupSparkContext() {

            SparkConf sc = new SparkConf();

            return App.getSparkContext("helloworld", sc);
        }
    }
```